# typing of intrinsic-call and typing of static-get-item error

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have got a `numba.njit` function which manipulates a numpy array with a manual dtype declaration and experiencing the following errors

```
[1m[1m[1mNo implementation of function Function(<built-in function getitem>) found for signature:

 >>> getitem(Record(e[type=int32;offset=0],c[type=int32;offset=4],b[type=int32;offset=8],f[type=int32;offset=12];16;False), Literal[int](0))

There are 22 candidate implementations:
[1m     - Of which 22 did not match due to:
     Overload of function 'getitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
       With argument(s): '(Record(e[type=int32;offset=0],c[type=int32;offset=4],b[type=int32;offset=8],f[type=int32;offset=12];16;False), int64)':[0m
[1m      No match.[0m
[0m
[0m[1mDuring: typing of intrinsic-call at D:\maxint.py (50)[0m
[0m[1mDuring: typing of static-get-item at D:\maxint.py (50)[0m
[1m
File "maxint.py", line 50:[0m
[1mdef func (aa, f1,f2,f3,f0,g1,g2,g3,g0):
    <source elided>
    for i in range(aa1.shape[0]):
[1m        aa1[i][0] = aa[i][0] + f0 + g0
[0m        [1m^[0m[0m
```

the following are the snippect of the code

```
dtypeS = [('e',int), ('c',int), ('b',int),('f',int)]
aa = numpy.array (obj1, dtype=dtypeS)

@numba.njit(fastmath = True)
def func (aa, f1,f2,f3,f0,g1,g2,g3,g0):

    aa1 = numpy.empty(shape=(aa.shape[0],4))
    for i in range(aa1.shape[0]):
        aa1[i][0] = aa[i][0] + f0 + g0
```

If I remove the `dtype=` code, everything would be fine. Does this mean numba does not support manual dtype delcaration of the numpy array?

Comment: Could you try to copy the terminal in such a way that the encoding is not messed up?

Comment: Which numba version are you on? This code works for me.

Comment: Update numba. Doesn't work in `0.53.1`, fixed in `0.54.0`